# How to import data from Repeating form Sharepoint 2010

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath form setup on a Sharepoint List that allows the user to enter multiple Repeating Forms concurrently (so 2 or more entries with the same Submit call).

1. User navigates to the list
2. User clicks "New Item" ->InfoPath opens
3. User fills out a form in its entirety, and then clicks the "  Insert Item" button at the bottom left of the filled out form
4. A Repeating Section opens

I'd like there to be a button they could select that would enter data from a previous form, or the previous Repeating Form entry.

It is a lengthy form and there could potentially be 5 or 6 entries per project.

[image]

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific?  Are you dealing with repeating sections?  Have you promoted some of your fields when publishing to a form library?

Comment: ok I just edited

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a secondary data connection to get back items from previously submitted forms, BUT only for columns that you have promoted during publishing.  You will need to filter the secondary source using some value in a field on your current form and a rule to trigger it (it doesn't need to necessarily be triggered by a button push).  As for the repeating section, you will need to use XPath, some private fields, and some clever string manipulation--it's not for the faint of heart!

Some useful links:

- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/filter-the-data-that-is-displayed-in-a-control-HA101783367.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx
- http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/automatically-populate-repeating-table-infopath-sequential-dates.htm
- http://alecpojidaev.wordpress.com/2010/01/07/accessing-previous-rows-in-repeating-group-for-browser-enabled-forms/

Comment: I think what you are saying here is that I first have to have a list item submitted.  All fields are 'promoted', this is a SharePoint List originated InfoPath form. I know how to use DC to pull an already existing form instance into the current form but I wanted to do this BEFORE the form was submitted.

Comment: I see. Basically you will have to use hidden fields to and some rules.  If the data is coming from a repeating section, you will have to use XPath to navigate through the repeating section XML, which can get kind of messy.  In fact, you may be better off skipping the repeating section and just create a set number of fields that are hidden or displayed based on the user entry--you could even create a button that looks like the "New Item" that will display the next field.  I only say this because I know how painful it can be to navigate through the repeating section using XPath.

Comment: No this still isn't it. The ENTIRE FORM is getting entered 2 or more times. It isn't a "Repeating Section", it is "Repeating Form".

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong, but you are copying whole sections of the form over and over again?  I am having a hard time understanding the idea behind the "repeating form"--data should only be entered once and displayed how ever way you want displayed or copied into how many other fields you have, and this can be done all before you submit.  If you want to take this offline, let me know.